# PHP MD5 not working correctly

Tags: php, md5

So I'm using md5 to encode and decode passwords when users register and login, however the password in my database doesn't match the password used when logging in even though I know they are the same word:

This is what is in my database

098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832

And this is what using md5 on the password used on the login screen gives me

098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6

As you can see there are 7 additional characters, but I can't tell why they aren't the same. Here is the script used for inserting the user details into the database on registering

```
$qry =  "INSERT INTO Members(fname, lname, fullname, email, login, passwd, bad_league_id) 
         VALUES('$fname','$lname',0,'$email', '$login','".md5($_POST['password'])."',0)";
$result = @mysql_query($qry);
```

And here is how my login form compares the values

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM Members WHERE login='$login' AND passwd='".md5($_POST['password'])."'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);
```

On another note, I am currently in the process of transferring over from mysql to mysqli so forgive the use of mysql as I know its deprecated.

Comment: What is the SQL datatype of the password field in the database? Is it `VARCHAR (25)` by an chance?

Comment: Yes, it's a varchar(25) and I'm using collation utf8_unicode_ci. Please tell me that means you know how to fix it :-)

Comment: How long is the field? Keep in mind md5 has not been safe for passwords for like six or seven years at least (longer?). You should be using `crypt()` with BLOWFISH.

Comment: I've just realised myself, the field isn't long enough!!!

Comment: [PHP FAQ - Passwords](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)

Comment: Please please please stop rolling out your own password hashing method. Use the [native API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php) when you are on PHP 5.5. Or the [compatibility library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) when on 5.3.7+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the hash generated by the `MD5()` function is 32 characters long. The datatype of the `passwd` column is currently `VARCHAR (25)`, which means it will only store up to 25 characters, 7 characters less than the actual value.

To fix this, you will need to change the datatype of the `passwd` column to be able to store the correct length, e.g. `VARCHAR (32)`.